# "Call to undefined function str_slug()" in Laravel 6.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, laravel-helper

I've upgraded my laravel 5.8 project to 6.0. It has upgraded successfully but when I'm trying to run the project or installing another package to my project it is giving me error named as "Call to undefined function str_slug()" in session.php. I don't know why....

`Call to undefined function str_slug()`

Comment: `str_slug()` is not available in `6.0`. They have changed it to `Str::slug`. Looks like some of your Laravel code is still from `5.8`

Comment: problem solved... Thanks :)

Comment: I have the same issue, but the str_slug is from the cache.php and session.php files supplied by laravel. How do I get more recent versions of these files?

Comment: when you update your project into 6.0 these files will be automatic updated at their location if not available then will be created. Run `composer update` from your terminal

Comment: I had the same problem as mankowitz, but composer update didn't update them. I went on the github of laravel to get the latest code and updated confg/cache.php and config/session.php manually.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

If you have gone through the [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers) then you must know that

**String** and **Array** Helpers have been [removed](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php#L1071) from Core Framework

So if if You need to still use the helper install the package

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

and all the helpers are moved to this package

Comment: hi. i have the same problem. after `composer require laravel/helpers` the problem didn't solved. is there any thing i must do?

Comment: is it a fresh installation of laravel 6.0 or Upgraded to 6.0 ??

Comment: It's about upgrade to 6.0

Comment: I was struggling by using Str_plural, then realized in 6* it has to be Str::_plural, but that was still not working but by installing the laravel/helpers package, and clearing the artisan cache/config etc... it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 41):

String and Array helpers are removed from laravel 6.0 Core Framework

https://laravel.com/docs/6.0/upgrade#helpers

So if You need to still use the helper install the package

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Or you can use by Laravel facade

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
$slug = Str::slug('Laravel 5 Framework', '-');
```

Answer (score 5):

Personal I hard to do the following on Laravel 6
on the app Controllers add this `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` then
something like this  `'slug' => Str::slug($request->title)`

Comment: I don't have any idea about it but I've already got a solution. Thank you

Comment: Yes, it works for all Laravel version. ``Illuminate\Support\Str::slug($title);``

Answer (score 2):

There are two options to resolve the issue of `call to undefined function str_slug()`.

1.You should run the command `composer require laravel/helpers`

Or another option is when you don't want to install packages then this below solution is the easy way to solve your issue and it is the best way.

2.You can use facades class

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function index(Request $request)
{
   $slug = Str::slug($request->name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$post = Post::create([
'slug'      => S t r::slug($request->title),
here we go

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

composer require laravel/helpers

php artisan optimize:clear

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).