# After upgrading Laravel from 5.6 to 6.0, Call to undefined str_random() function not working

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, laravel-helper, laravel-upgrade

I have upgraded Laravel from 5.6 to 6.0. Previously, default helper functions were running fine on the controllers, but now it says "**undefined**." In my controller, I have used the following.

```php
$filename = str_random(12);
```

I am getting the following error.

> message: "Call to undefined function
>   App\Http\Controllers\str_random()"

I have also used the `random()` function, and it's saying the same thing.

Can somebody please guide me on what to do?.

I have run commands like:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned `str_random()` was removed in 5.8, doesn't look like it's supported at all. Try this instead:
https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-random

Comment: Could you please post where in the documentation it says "those functions" are still supported? https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/helpers#method-str-random says it's `Str::random()`

Comment: @kerbholz : hello sir, i am very sorry, i have seen 5.6 documentation in place of 6.0

now i have pull down the top select box and set version as 6.0, not i can see what you have written is right

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Call to undefined function str\_slug()" in Laravel 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864711/call-to-undefined-function-str-slug-in-laravel-6-0)

Answer (score 118, accepted):

> Likelihood Of Impact: High [Laravel 6 Upgrade Guide](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/upgrade#helpers)

In Laravel 6 All `str_` and `array_` helpers have been moved to the new `laravel/helpers` Composer package and **removed from the framework**. If desired, you may update all calls to these helpers to use the `Illuminate\Support\Str` and `Illuminate\Support\Arr` classes. Alternatively, you can add the new `laravel/helpers` package to your application to continue using these helpers:

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

If don't want to add Package then Used `Str` And `Arr` Classes.

For Example :

```
Str::random(12)
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/helpers#method-str-random

Comment: Str::replace is not there, instead what Can I use? if i want to replace with?

Comment: use the built-in `str_replace` function otherwise follow my answer.

Answer (score 42):

Add the following string library.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
```

now you can use it as below.

```
$filename = Str::random(40)
```

alternatively, install the following package.

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't use any of the string helpers in my app code, so I just had to remove the compiled class file:

```
php artisan clear-compiled
```

Answer (score -1):

use code ::

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Exception;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;



   public function index()
    {
        $count=15;
        try {
            DB::statement('truncate users');
            DB::beginTransaction();
            while ($count--){
                $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId( [
                    'name'=>'Sample'.$count,
                    'password'=>random_int(1000000,99999999)
                ]);
                foreach (range(1,rand(1,3)) as $index ){
                    DB::insert('INSERT INTO posts (userid,title,body) VALUES (:userid,:title,:body)',[
                            'userid'=>$id,
                            'title'=>str::random(15),
                            'body'=>str::random(50),
                        ]);
                }
                DB::commit();
            }
        }catch (\Exception $errors){
            DB::rollBack();
            Log::error($errors);
            return "mission filed";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Too much redundant code, sorry.