# Laravel table saves wrong data

Tags: php, laravel, string, random

I have string column in my table which supposed to store unique tokens but instead it stores something like this:

```
??6?i!a\????5?&?9?
```

## Code

`controller`

```
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

public function store(Request $request)
{
  $recipient = new RsvpPerson;
  $recipient->token = Str::random(20);
  $recipient->save();
}
```

`Schema`

```
Schema::create('rsvp_people', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->uuid('id')->primary();
    $table->string('token')->unique();
    $table->timestamps();
}
```

**any idea?**

Comment: @KamleshPaul yes mix of letters and numbers, capital or not...

Comment: @KamleshPaul I think I must install helper package (trying it now...)   https://stackoverflow.com/a/58163479/8490993

Comment: using laravel 7, apparently they've removed it from defaults

Comment: seems like it was there already, then why doesn't work?!

Comment: What does `echo Illuminate\Support\Str::random(10);` return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solved

I'm not sure why laravel helper doesn't work but using this solved the problem

```
str_random(20)
```