# Update from Laravel 5.5 to 6

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to update the Laravel5.5 project to 6.
What I tried is first describing the package update

```
"php": "^7.2",
"ext-SimpleXML": "^7.3",
"barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.6",
"doctrine/dbal": "^2.10",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^2.0",
"laravel/framework": "^6.0",
"laravel/tinker": "~1.0",
"laravelcollective/html": "^6.0",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"laravel/ui": "^1.1",
"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9",
"phpoffice/phpexcel": "dev-master"
```

next

`composer update`

I get error

> Call to undefined function str_slug()

So install this library

```
composer require laravel/helpers
```

Then this error came out

> JeroenNoten \ LaravelAdminLte \ ServiceProvider :: class, not found

Reinstalling adminLTE doesn't help, commenting out and reinstalling doesn't work, I'm stuck and want help

I need help

Comment: You are using the wrong serviceprovider for adminlte package. Actually, you don't need to add it service provider to app.php, Laravel will autoload it.

Comment: @EliasSoares I knew it was added automatically, so I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: "it didn't work", what didn't work? what actually happened and what was your expectation of what would happen?

Comment: @lagbox The error content did not change

Comment: you commented what out?

Comment: @lagbox this is JeroenNoten \ LaravelAdminLte \ ServiceProvider :: class

Comment: if you had cached the config previously you will need to delete the cached config, which it shouldn't be cached in development anyway ... and what is with the spaces between everything?

Comment: @lagbox Do I need to delete my cache after git clone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click here to resolve this error: [Call to undefined function str_slug()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57864711/call-to-undefined-function-str-slug-in-laravel-6-0/57864769#57864769)

---

Remove space in `config/app.php` file:

```
'providers' => [

    ....

    JeroenNoten\LaravelAdminLte\ServiceProvider::class,

],
```

---

Just run this command, It can automatically add all configurations to your project:

```
composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte
```

More info about [jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte](https://packagist.org/packages/jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte)

Comment: According to you mention ```composer require jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte``` . It upgrade to latest version. I don't want latest version and I want  ```"jeroennoten/laravel-adminlte": "^2.0"``` How to do it? I got also same error ```JeroenNoten \ LaravelAdminLte \ ServiceProvider :: class, not found```

Answer (score 0):

Open the `composer.json` file of your project (The configuration file of Composer) and change the Laravel framework . `(Notice the caret, Laravel 6 makes use of semantic versioning scheme)`.

you are recommended to first upgrade your project to `5.8` then again upgrade to `v6`.

Next, save your composer.json file and run the following command:

> $ composer update

Before you upgrade your project to v6, make sure your upgrade your PHP version from 7.1 to at least 7.2.

starting from December 2019, PHP 7.1 will not be maintained.